# rChart in Markdown doesn't render due to InvalidUrlException from Pandoc

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, rcharts

I'm trying to embed a simple scatter plot using the `rCharts` library and it's not working. Following along with the answers I found on several SO questions, I came up with this code:

````
``` {r, results = "asis", comment = NA}
library(rCharts)
p <- rPlot(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars, type = "point")
p$print("chart", include_assets = TRUE)
```
````

However, when I knit the markdown document, I get this error:

```
pandoc.exe: Could not fetch C:/Playground/R-3.2.2/library/rCharts/libraries/polycharts/js/polychart2.standalone.js
InvalidUrlException "C:/Playground/R-3.2.2/library/rCharts/libraries/polycharts/js/polychart2.standalone.js" "Invalid scheme"
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 67
```

Googling this error shows that Pandoc seems to have some issues with absolute paths. Some suggestions have been to update RStudio and to use relative paths. The former isn't a solution because I'm up to date and the latter isn't a solution because the filepath is specified by the function, not by me.

**My question, then, is are there any other solutions to get this to work?**

Here is my session info:

```
Session info ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (0.99.441)          
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/New_York            
 date     2015-11-24                  

Packages --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package    * version    date       source                                            
 devtools     1.9.1      2015-09-11 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                                     
 gtable       0.1.2      2012-12-05 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                   
 htmltools    0.2.6      2014-09-08 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                   
 httr         1.0.0      2015-06-25 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                                     
 R6           2.1.1      2015-08-19 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                   
 rCharts    * 0.4.5      2015-10-26 Github (ramnathv/rCharts@389e214)                  
 rmarkdown  * 0.8.1      2015-10-10 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                     
 whisker      0.3-2      2013-04-28 CRAN (R 3.2.2)                   
 yaml         2.1.13     2014-06-12 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
```

Comment: The uri parsing routines pandoc uses allow "C:" as as a scheme, so pandoc treats your absolute path as a URL.  I'll fix this so that single-letter schemes aren't allowed.  (Pandoc maintainer.)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond; it's definitely appreciated. Is there any work around that I can use in the meantime?

Comment: You can install pandoc from source.

Comment: I'm working through that now based on your tutorial https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Installing-the-development-version-of-pandoc, but when I `cd pandoc; cabal install --force --enable-tests` I get an error saying it cannot resolve dependencies. It rejects texmath-0.8.4 all the way down to 0.1. Any chance you'd be willing to help with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've realized that it might be because even after running `cd pandoc-types; cabal install --force` and it returning that it has in fact installed that package, it's no where to be found. I only have pandoc-types-1.12.4.

Comment: Sorry, we're in a transitional phase now where pandoc depends on unreleased versions of pandoc-types and texmath (I should have said that before).  So you need to use the stack tool to install.  Grab the binary here https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/releases and then, in the pandoc source directory:  `stack setup`, `stack install`.  Then make sure the install directory is in your path.  PS although I happened to stumble across this, pandoc-discuss is a better place for questions about pandoc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'll give it a go. If it doesn't work, I'll move the conversation over to pandoc-discuss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, so after hours of struggling to get this to work, I have finally figured out a solution using John MacFarlane's comments and his tutorial, which can be found [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Installing-the-development-version-of-pandoc). If you're on Windows, there's a couple things that you need to know in order for this to work.

First and foremost, after you install the Haskell Platform, `cabal` is not immediately available if you don't have admin rights on your computer. As a result, you'll need to manually enter the filepath into your `PATH` variable. The path is `/path_to_Haskell/lib/extralibs/bin`.

Now that you can call `cabal` from the command line, you should be aware of the fact that `cabal update` takes **forever** to run. I use that term loosely, but it's a good 10 to 15 minutes.

Next, you'll want to work through John's tutorial. When you get to the part where you're in the `pandoc` folder after cloning the github repo, try to run `cabal install --force --enable-tests` first. If it doesn't fail, then you should be good to go. For me, since they were in a transition phase when I did this, you'll get a message that says there were some conflicts and it will say it has exhausted the dependency tree. If this happens, download [the stack binary](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/releases) that John links to in his comments. Then, in the `pandoc` directory, run `stack setup` and then `stack install`.

Once this is done, continue with John's tutorial to clone `pandoc-citeproc` and install it. At this point, you're unfortunately still not done. For me, R was now trying to use `C:/Users/brittenb/AppData/Roaming/cabal/bin/pandoc.exe` which isn't the right executable file. That's the executable that was created when we installed `pandoc-citeproc` and is (at the time of this writing) version 15.2.1, which doesn't include the filepath fix. We want the executable built by stack, which should be saved in your `~/AppData/Roaming/local/bin` directory. Simply copy the `pandoc.exe` file to `~/AppData/Roaming/cabal/bin`.

Finally, restart R and knit your markdown to HTML. All should be well and good.